# Meaning of "And I came her majestic reflections to know"?

Tags: sentence-meaning, inversion, poetry

> One stood among them, I remember most clearly
>   Her sorrows were heavy, and her laughter was slow
>   I courted her gently, for I loved her most dearly
>   *And I came her majestic reflections to know*

I have seen this sentence in a music, but I really can't understand it, because I never saw such construction before.

That equals to "I knew her majestic thoughts" or "I came to know her majestic thoughts"?

Comment: It's an unusual poetic inversion (primarily justifiable here because it *rhymes*) that simply conveys your *second* meaning more awkwardly . I would avoid it like the plague. Theoretically it could carry a different sense *(The **reason** I came was to find out about her majestic reflections)*, but I think we can safely ignore that one.

Comment: @FumbleFingers - could "reflections" mean "nuances of her character" or ".. of her body", I wonder. Something like this. Like "majestic faucets of a diamond". A diamond reflects light. Or it must necessarily be "thoughts".

Comment: A excellent comparison with a diamond. Looking in your point view, this may mean that he knew all sides of her, her thoughts, sex desires, character, everything. He knew her completely.

Comment: @CopperKettle, Apprentice: I think the "inversion" aspect is on topic, but not the interpretation. Diamond *facets* (not *faucets* = American *taps!* :) is a perfectly credible allusion. But the *complete* context might affect things. But of course she may be a bit of a philosopher, and her *reflections* may be her *musings on life, the universe, and everything*. You pays your money and you takes your choice.

Comment: @FumbleFingers You're right, because this poetry is so cool hehe

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure, "reflections" can mean either expressions of inner thoughts or more literally, reflections of her presumed beauty, such as in a mirror.  But that's probable the point of the question...

The construction is just a poetic rearrangement of the sentence parts and is essentially equivalent to:

> And i came to know her majestic reflection.

This has become a common form in the English since Yoda first appeared in Star Wars: The Empire Strikes Back.